# VBA windowresize event not triggering with Windows Snap

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a function that triggers on the `workbook_windowresize` event

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
   Call ResizeFunction
End Sub
```

From what I can tell, the event is not triggered when the window is resized with Windows 10 Snap Assist. Does anyone know the cause of this or a solution for it?

Thanks

Edit: If it's relevant I'm using Excel 365

Comment: Just to clarify, I've tried this out on my computer and the function will call when you snap with the Windows+Arrow shortcut, or if you snap by snapping another window first and choosing it from the Snap Assist menu, but it won't work if you snap the window using the mouse to drag the window to one of the corners. Is this what you are experiencing?

Comment: @girlvsdata Yes it is. Dragging the window to the top of the screen not triggering the event is the thing that's the most inconvenient.

Comment: I'm looking into an answer for this, currently I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: It does fire if the windows was initially maximized (twice), but not in the other cases. Weird.

Comment: As a possible, at least temporary workaround, consider adding code to another even which should fire whenever resize fires, namely the paint event.  I'm speaking from VB6 experience, so I don't know that Excel VBA has the same even (form_Paint) or equivalent, but hopefully the idea will at least guide you to an alternative solution.

Comment: Another possible trigger might be to issue the equivalent of a form.Refresh method.

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks, but I'm not sure if those work with Excel, and if they do I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: I seem to recall the Excel VBA IDE working very similar to VB 6's IDE, so you might want to look at the events that are available for your workbook_windowXXX events.  If Workbook_WindowReSize() is a built-in even and not a custom method (sub) there may be others that are usable.  In my Windows Apps (VB6) I sometimes place code interchangeably in form_ReSize and form_Paint events since both are actually called when a form resizes, I believe.  It may be the same in VBA.  If you have the form selected in design mode, can you select a pull-down for events?

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I looked through all the events for workbook_ and worksheet_, I couldn't find any that triggered when snapping the window.

Comment: @Kerry I've put the question to the Super User community as well, here: https://superuser.com/questions/1340445/window-resize-event-not-triggering-when-snapping-windows-to-the-edge-of-the-scre I think it might be a limitation of the WindowResize event, possibly? I haven't had anyone bite on that question yet, but it might be worth following along nonetheless.